# Cleanest way to prematurely exit a Jenkins job as a success?

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job which is calling a shell script. The behavior of the shell script is like it is in while loop which make sure that the service is always on (never exit) and runs in background.

Shell script: startFastCGIservers.sh
Jenkins Job: This job will take parameter i.e. start/stop/restart and server name and do a service restart/start/stop. But when I am trying to do a start/restart my Jenkins job never ends. everytime I need to abort the job to make it successful.

Jenkins job Shell executor is like below:

```
case ${service} in
 fwkmodmap)
  case ${action} in
       start) ssh ${LOGIN}@${Server} "/home/${LOGIN}/script/adm/startserverfwkmodmap.sh"
             ;;
       stop) ssh ${LOGIN}@${Server} "/home/${LOGIN}/script/adm/stopserverfwkmodmap.sh"
             ;;
       restart) ssh ${LOGIN}@${Server} "/home/${LOGIN}/script/adm/stopserverfwkmodmap.sh"
                ssh ${LOGIN}@${Server} "/home/${LOGIN}/script/adm/startserverfwkmodmap.sh"
                ;;
       *) echo "Usage : $0 { start | stop | restart }"
          exit 1
          ;;
  esac
```

Can anyone please suggest what I can do to exit this Jenkins job with success message?

Comment: I suppose the issue is the ssh cmd is waiting for the script to exit and since it is running, it has not exit. You need to spawn off the process (nohup?). You can do so in the remote call OR alter your sh to spawn the process.

Comment: I just added forwarded the out to /dev/null and it worked for me:

ssh ${LOGIN}@${Server} "/home/${LOGIN}/script/adm/startserverfwkmodmap.sh" > /dev/null

Comment: That is an odd solution/ workaround.

Comment: I tried to create a new script say abc.sh
nohup /home/${LOGIN}/script/adm/startserverfwkmodmap.sh &
 and called abc.sh with Jenkins and it keeps on running on Jenkins frontend.
So I did abc.sh > /dev/null